# docker-machine with "generic" driver: security concerns

Tags: security, docker, sudo, docker-machine

I want to use docker-machine to deploy containers on a Debian 9 server from my local computer.

I followed instructions from [this page](https://blog.dahanne.net/2015/10/07/adding-an-existing-docker-host-to-docker-machine-a-few-tips/), which clearly indicates:

> If you are using « sudo » on the host, make sure you configure
>   passwordless sudo:
>
> ```
> # visudo
> %sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
> ```

In addition, [docker documentation for `generic` docker-machine driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/#sudo-privileges) mention the same:

> **Sudo privileges**
>
> The user that is used to SSH into the host can be specified with `--generic-ssh-user` flag. This user needs password-less sudo privileges. If it’s not the case, you need to edit the `sudoers` file and configure the user as a sudoer with `NOPASSWD`

I'm not an expert, but I feel something is wrong here... Doesn't allowing a user on a production server to execute any command without password open a security breach? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 months later, I think I have an answer to my own question. It appear that the passwordless configuration is needed only when the production server is first registered in docker-machine.

Once command `docker-machine create --driver generic [...]` has been sucessfully entered, `docker-machine` is able to connect to remote host using socket on port 2376, and `sudo` is not used anymore on production server.

In other words, passwordless sudo configuration should be present a few seconds on the server, and may be disabled later.